Scaffold appBar not accepting stateless widget implementing PreferredSizeWidget
Im trying to make a custom appbar, i've found that implementing preferredSizeWidget in a statelesswidget would make it work and it makes it work, but for some reason one of my custom appbars doesnt get accepted by the scaffold with error:

The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'.

This is navigation.dart:
Scaffold(
  appBar: [
    const HomeAppBar(),
    const AccountAppBar(),
    const SettingsAppBar(),
    ][pageIndex],
  body: ...
);

HomeAppBar() and SettingsAppBar() are accepted without a problem, but AccountAppBar: gets the error
This is the implementation for all 3 appBar widgets:
class AccountAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const AccountAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}

For some reason AccountAppBar() is only accepted as a stateful widget and doesn't cause any problems

Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

When I tested that code it shows the error on the whole list, not just the AccountAppBar(). Perhaps your other app bars are Stateful? In that case what I would guess is happening is that the two different types of widgets are be type-elevated to their most obvious common ancestor (the type "Widget").
Give this a shot:
appBar: <PreferredSizeWidget>[
  const HomeAppBar(),
  const AccountAppBar(),
  const SettingsAppBar(),
][pageIndex],

That will explicitly type the List and not rely on the analyzer's inference system.

this has indeed solved my problem, thanks for help
